Whatsapp Webhook data in PHP
I have been playing with this now for a week and can't seems to find a solution. Whatsapp Business API is set up and working 100% in Live. I have verified my Webhook but are not able to see any data coming into the webhook file since the verification.
Many variations of code have been tried to get data but still I don't see any data on the file, even when testing from the Quickstart > Configuration page.
The code I am currently running is from an answer provided by @Tarik at the following post: (for facebook itself but coding is the same)
Facebook Messenger API - Can't verify webhook URL (PHP)
My webhook.php file is:
$message = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value){
    $message .= "$key => $value (".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].")\n";
}
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
$array = print_r(json_decode($input, true), true);
file_put_contents('log.txt', $message.$array."\nREQUEST_METHOD: $_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD]\n----- Request Date: ".date("d.m.Y H:i:s")." IP: $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] -----\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
if ( isset($_REQUEST['hub_challenge']) ){
    echo $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
}

When sending a test from the Webhook Configuration page, the log.txt file only returns this:
2024-08-08 13:17:38
REQUEST_METHOD: GET
----- Request Date: 08.08.2024 13:17:38 IP: 173.252.107.116 -----

I am a bit stuck here and also lost on ideas. Can anyone advise me how to actually read the data I should receive on the webhook? I was considering playing with the verification token to see if Meta require it for some sort of asynchronous communication but that don't seem to be the case. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Only the requests made to initially verify your webhook URL during the setup phase, should be GET requests. The actual notifications should come as POST requests - and therefor same when you send a test request from the UI.

@CBroe that is also how I understand it. I have tested both GET and POST. The above script I currently run for testing do use the REQUEST method to capture both GET and POST.

The POST request will be Content-Type: application/json, so PHP will not populate $_POST in this case - and therefor you won't find the values in $_REQUEST either. But as long as your script logs REQUEST_METHOD: GET, something else must be going wrong already. Instead of checking only your self-written log file there, you should check your server's access log, to see what requests are actually reaching your server.

@CBroe, I followed your advise, the log give POST /whatsapp/webhook HTTP/1.1 301 707. I tried looking into that with no success thus far. It can't be a 'moved permanent' error as it is the same URL as verified. I also played with the Callback URL by adding and removing the last slash, as well as indicating the actual file. No success yet. Struggle to find answers on the net for this but still looking.

This definitively is a redirect, the log has noted the response status code as 301. "It can't be a 'moved permanent' error as it is the same URL as verified." - verifying happened via GET, and apparently your system reacts differently to GET and POST requests here. And clients usually follow up a 301-redirected POST, by making a GET request for the same URL - so that's how you lose all the actual data here.

This sound like something I have to take up with the server host. Is that what you would suggest?

The solution was the true URL. In my case I was not providing a / at the end of the URL (my Callback URL is only showing to the directory and not the file itself).
It was something like : https://demourl.com/webhook
It needed to be: https://demourl.com/webhook/
For anybody facing the same situation, you can use https://www.whatsmydns.net/redirect-checker to check your true URL.
Also note, I had to remove the Webhook subscription and add it anew in order to actually pick up the URL change. Just changing it didn't do the trick.
Big shoutout to @CBroe for guiding me into the right direction!!!
